# Mapped Contact Form Not Function Properly in Jquery-1.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have code for a no longer supported map marker form.
It works fine on jquery-1.6.1.min.js (its original).

What I want is for it to work on jquery-1.11 (the webpage I need it to work on depends on this, I cannot fall back).

**What The Issue Is:**

If try to use the form it successfully sends the message but the issue is it opens the 'acknowledge message sent' in a new web page instead of being contained in the map info box the same size as the form.

When using v1.11 I keep getting this error in Chrome console:

*'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'*

on

*'mappedcontactformpro.js:199'*

[I've set up a test page here:](http://bit.ly/17aEiRD)

Any idea how to fix this to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.
I suspected it was a jquery backward compatibility issue and it was.
I added these 2 lines directly after the jquery script in the header:

```
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

I found the answer here:
[jquery migration page](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)

If anyone else has this issue with the mapped contact form I hope it solves it for them too

Comment: It's not the ideal solution because it means there are more js scripts loading, but it does work. I'm going to remove the test page in the initial question.